# Union vs Unionwith in HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset

What the difference between  `HashSet.Union`  vs `HashSet.Unionwith`  when i combine 2 hashsets.

I am trying to combine like this:

```
HashSet<EngineType> enginesSupportAll = _filePolicyEvaluation.EnginesSupportAll;
        enginesSupportAll = enginesSupportAll != null ? new HashSet<EngineType>(engines.Union(enginesSupportAll)) : enginesSupportAll;
```

what is the best method for this example and why?

Comment: `UnionWith` mutates the receiver, `Union` returns a sequence containing the union of two sequences.

Comment: UnionWith modifies your original HashSet (in this case, enginesSupportAll) by adding all elements in the second 'other' set. Union creates a new HashSet with the same elements as the above collection, however it has an additional optional parameter that allows you to specify an IEqualityComparer, which can change which elements are produced in the result.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, it's not `HashSet.Union` but [`Enumerable.Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx), so you are using a LINQ extension method that works with any kind of `IEnumerable<>` whereas [`HashSet.UnionWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097(v=vs.110).aspx) is a real `HashSet` method that modifes the current instance.

- `Union` returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>`
- `UnionWith` is `void`, it modifies the current `HashSet` instance
- maybe `UnionWith` is slightly more efficient because it can be optimized

If you don't want to support any kind of sequence in your method so `HashSet` is fix and you can modify it, use that, otherwise use the LINQ extension.
If you create the `HashSet` instance just for this purpose it doesn't really matter and i would prefer LINQ to be more flexible and to be able to chain my query.

Answer (score 51):

Given [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) *A* and `HashSet<T>` *B* there are four ways to *A* ∪ *B*:

1. `new HashSet<t>(A.Union(B))`
    <sub>*(see [`HashSet<T&>(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504(v=vs.110).aspx%20%22HashSet(T)%20Constructor%20(IEnumerable(T))%20(System.Collections.Generic)%20%7C%20MSDN%22)) and
   [`Enumerable.Union<T>(IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx))*</sub>
2. [`A.UnionWith(B)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. `HashSet<T> C = new HashSet<T>(A); C.UnionWith(B);`
4. `new HashSet<t>(A.Concat(B))`
   <sub>*(see [`Enumerable.Concat<T>(IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx))*</sub>

Each has its advantages and disadvantages:

- 1 and 4 are expressions that results in a `HashSet` whereas 2 and 3 are statements or statement blocks.
  Expression 1 and 4 can be used in more places than 2 and 3. For example, using 2 or 3 in a linq query syntax expression is cumbersome:
  `from x in setofSetsA as IEnumerable<HashSet<T>>
  from y in setOfSetsB as IEnumerable<HashSet<T>>
  select x.UnionWith(y)` will not work since `UnionWith` returns void.
- 1, 3, and 4 preserve *A* and *B* as they are and return a fresh set whereas 2 modifies *A*.
  There are situations where modifying one of the original sets is bad and there are situations where at least one of the original sets can be modified without negative consequences.
- Computational cost:

  `A.UnionWith(B)`
  (≈ O((log(|A∪B|) - log(|A|)) * |A∪B|) + O(|B|))

  ≤

  `HashSet<T> C = new HashSet<T>(A); C.UnionWith(B);`
  (≈ O((log(|A∪B|) - log(|A|)) * |A∪B|) + O(|A| + |B|))

  ≤

  `HashSet<T>(A.Concat(B))`
  (≈ O(log(|A∪B|) * |A∪B|) + O(|A| + |B|))

  ≤

  `HashSet<T>(A.Union(B))`
  (≈ 2 * O(log(|A∪B|) * |A∪B|) + O(|A| + |B| + |A∪B|))

  The next section delves into the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) to see the basis of these performance estimates.

## Performance

### [`HashSet<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs)

In union option 1, 3, and 4 the constructor [`HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>, IEqualityComparer<T>)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,d0822f25708256c5) is used to create a `HashSet<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.
If the passed `IEnumerable<T>` has a [`Count` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.count(v=vs.110).aspx) —i.e. if it is an [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx)—, this property is used to set the size of the new `HashSet`:

> ```
> int suggestedCapacity = 0;
> ICollection<T> coll = collection as ICollection<T>;
> if (coll != null) {
>     suggestedCapacity = coll.Count;
> }
> Initialize(suggestedCapacity);
> ```
>
> -- [`HashSet.cs` line 136–141](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,139)

The `[Count()][10]` method is never called.  So if the `IEnumerable`'s count can be retrieved without effort it is used to reserve capacity; otherwise the `HashSet` grows and reallocates when new elements are added.
In option 1 `A.Union(B)` and option 4 `A.Concat(B)` are not `ICollection<T>` therefore the created `HashSet` will grow and reallocate a few (≈ log(|A∪B|)) times.  Option 3 can use the `Count` of *A*.

The constructor calls [`UnionWith`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,71347988796dc52f) to fill the new empty `HashSet`:

> ```
> this.UnionWith(collection);
> ```
>
> -- [`HashSet.cs` line 143](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,143)

`UnionWith(IEnumerable<T>)` iterates over the elements in the `IEnumerable<T>` passed as argument and calls [`AddIfNotPresent(T)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,188b8f94f8fc999b) for each.

`AddIfNotPresent(T)` inserts elements and ensures that duplicates are never inserted into the set.
`HashSet<T>` is implemented as an array of slots, [`m_slots`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,018abcf5c92e31fc), and an array of buckets, [`m_buckets`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,7a31124d2d6de5c9).  A bucket contains just an `int` index into the `m_slots` array.  Per bucket the [`Slot`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,0e4026fbc70ce075)s in `m_slots` form a linked list with an index to the next `Slot` in `m_slots`.

`AddIfNotPresent(T)` jumps to the correct bucket and then traverses its linked list to check if the element is already present:

> ```
> for (int i = m_buckets[hashCode % m_buckets.Length] - 1; i >= 0; i = m_slots[i].next) {
>     if (m_slots[i].hashCode == hashCode && m_comparer.Equals(m_slots[i].value, value)) {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> -- [`HashSet.cs` line 968–975](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,968)

Next a free index is found and a slot is reserved.  First the list of free slots, [`m_freelist`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,0e8966240bf185c7), is checked.  When there are no slots in the freelist, the next empty slot in the `m_slots` array is used.  More capacity is reserved (via [`IncreaseCapacity()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,a26d80646fb023ea)) if there are no slots in the freelist and no empty slots:

> ```
> int index;
> if (m_freeList >= 0) {
>     index = m_freeList;
>     m_freeList = m_slots[index].next;
> }
> else {
>     if (m_lastIndex == m_slots.Length) {
>         IncreaseCapacity();
>         // this will change during resize
>         bucket = hashCode % m_buckets.Length;
>     }
>     index = m_lastIndex;
>     m_lastIndex++;
> }
> ```
>
> -- [`HashSet.cs` line 977–990](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,977)

`AddIfNotPresent(T)` has three operations that demand some computation: the call to [`object.GetHashCode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx), calling [`object.Equals(object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals(v=vs.110).aspx) when there is a collision, and `IncreaseCapacity()`.  The actual adding of an element only incurs the cost of setting some pointers and some ints.

When the `HashSet<T>` needs to `IncreaseCapacity()` the capacity is at least doubled.  Therefore we can conclude that on average a `HashSet<T>` is filled for 75%.  If the hashes are evenly distributed, the expectancy of a hash collision is also 75%.

[`SetCapacity(int, bool)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,9fbbf8ff7dbc0962), called by `IncreaseCapacity()`, is the most expensive: it allocates new arrays, it copies the old slot array to the new array, and it recalculates the bucket lists:

> ```
> Slot[] newSlots = new Slot[newSize];
> if (m_slots != null) {
>     Array.Copy(m_slots, 0, newSlots, 0, m_lastIndex);
> }
>
> ...
>
> int[] newBuckets = new int[newSize];
> for (int i = 0; i < m_lastIndex; i++) {
>     int bucket = newSlots[i].hashCode % newSize;
>     newSlots[i].next = newBuckets[bucket] - 1;
>     newBuckets[bucket] = i + 1;
> }
> m_slots = newSlots;
> m_buckets = newBuckets;
> ```
>
> -- [`HashSet.cs` line 929–949](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,929)

Option 1 and 4 (`new HashSet<T>(A.Union(B))`) will result in slightly more calls to `IncreaseCapacity()`.  The cost —without the cost of `A.Union(B)` or `A.Concat(B)`— is approximately **O(log(|A∪B|) * |A∪B|)**.
Whereas when using option 2 (`A.UnionWith(B)`) or option 3 (`HashSet<T> C = new HashSet<T>(A); C.UnionWith(B)`) we get a 'discount' of log(|A|) on the cost: **O((log(|A∪B|) - log(|A|)) * |A∪B|)**.  It pays (slightly) to use the largest set as the target into witch the other is merged.

### [`Enumerable<T>.Union(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f46b208108fc16dd)

`Enumerable<T>.Union(IEnumerable<T>)` is implemented via [`UnionIterator<T>(IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEqualityComparer<T>)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8c5b1699640b46dc).
The `UnionIterator` uses [`Set<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9c10b234c0932864) —an internal class in `Enumerable.cs`— that is very similar to `HashSet<T>`.  `UnionIterator` lazily [`Add(T)`s](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9b0b907c4d50b62a) items from *A* and *B* to this `Set<T>` and `yields` the elements if they could be added.  The work is done in [`Find(T, bool)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,71eda981b7574f10) which is similar to `HashSet<T>.AddIfNotPresent(T)`.  Check if the element is already present:

> ```
> int hashCode = InternalGetHashCode(value);
> for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length] - 1; i >= 0; i = slots[i].next) {
>     if (slots[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(slots[i].value, value)) return true;
> }
> ```
>
> -- [`Enumerable.cs` line 2423–2426](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2422)

Find a free index and reserve a slot:

> ```
> int index;
> if (freeList >= 0) {
>     index = freeList;
>     freeList = slots[index].next;
> }
> else {
>     if (count == slots.Length) Resize();
>     index = count;
>     count++;
> }
> int bucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
> slots[index].hashCode = hashCode;
> slots[index].value = value;
> slots[index].next = buckets[bucket] - 1;
> buckets[bucket] = index + 1;
> ```
>
> -- [`Enumerable.cs` line 2428–2442](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2428)

[`Resize()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,62b109ab980bf723) is similar to `IncreaseCapacity()`.  The biggest difference between the two is that `Resize()` does not use a [prime number](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,19337ead89202585) for the number of buckets, so with bad `GetHashCode()` there is a slightly higher chance for collisions.  Code of `Resize()`:

> ```
> int newSize = checked(count * 2 + 1);
> int[] newBuckets = new int[newSize];
> Slot[] newSlots = new Slot[newSize];
> Array.Copy(slots, 0, newSlots, 0, count);
> for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>     int bucket = newSlots[i].hashCode % newSize;
>     newSlots[i].next = newBuckets[bucket] - 1;
>     newBuckets[bucket] = i + 1;
> }
> buckets = newBuckets;
> slots = newSlots;
> ```
>
> -- [`Enumerable.cs` line 2448–2458](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2448)

The performance cost of `A.Union(B)` is not significantly different from that of `HashSet<T> C = new HashSet<T>(); C.UnionWith(A); C.UnionWith(B);`.  In option 1 (`new HashSet<T>(A.Union(B))`) the same `HashSet` is created twice resulting in a very costly 2 * O(log(|A∪B|) * (|A∪B|)).  Option 4 results from knowing how `HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` and `Enumerable.Union(IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>)` are implemented.  It avoids the redundant `A.Union(B)` leading to a cost of O(log(|A∪B|) * |A∪B|).

Comment: So, when I need to not modify the original `HashSet`, which of those two options would be better: `HashSet<T> C = new HashSet<T>(A); C.UnionWith(B);` or `HashSet<T>(A.Concat(B));`

Comment: It depends on what you need and the number of elements in the sets. `HashSet<T> C = new HashSet<T>(A); C.UnionWith(B);` is theoretically faster than `HashSet<T>(A.Concat(B))`. The latter is an expression and therefore usable in situations where the former, two statements, is not.  You will have to decide which expresses your intend more cleanly.  I would probably advise `HashSet<T>(A.Concat(B))`, despite it being somewhat slower in theory.

Comment: My lists are very short. Set A consists of nine and set B or two entries. Both are static readonly and no entries will be added on runtime. They contain database table column names with special properties ("editable", "interactive" and the combination of both).

Comment: @AndréReichelt in that case big O performance doesn't matter, choose what expresses your intended meaning best.  The expression variants do have the advantage that they can be assigned to a `static readonly` 'constant'. If `static readonly HashSet<string> editableColumns = new HashSet<string>(columnNames.Concat(editableNames))` is understandable to you and your readers use it, if `Union` expresses the intent better use `Union`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your further explanations.