# When are elements copied in 'List' operations (Concat())

Tags: c#, list

I have a data structure that contains 3 `Hashsets<T>`.
At some points I want to iterate over all sets at once. I required a `IEnumerable<T> GetCombined()` method.

1. What is the fastest way if I want to have copies?

```
return set1.ToList().Concat(set2.ToList()).Concat(set3.ToList());
```

2. What is the fasted way if I dont need to have copies?
   Is Concat doing copies automatically?

```
return set1.Concat(set2).Concat(set3)
```

(fast in sense of performance)

Comment: You can have a look at this existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917831/union-vs-unionwith-in-hashset)

Comment: Concat is lazily evaluated, if that's what you mean.

Comment: By copies, do you mean duplicates?

Comment: Copies of what? The `T` objects or the `HashSet`s?

Comment: Performancewise this is similar/equal. But I would consider copying the elements as the more fundamental definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a copy of the *entire* concatenated list, you can cut out two list creations:

```
return set1.Concat(set2).Concat(set3).ToList();
```

> What is the fasted way if I don't need to have copies? Is Concat doing copies automatically?

No - `Concat` is just a *query*, meaning that it will create an enumerator that will enumerate the underlying collections in order. No copies are created unless you use some method that hydrates a query (like `ToList()`)

Also note that `fastest` may be an unachievable goal. There may be micro-optimizations (pinning memory, etc.) that make it imperceptibly faster, but at the expense of more complex, harder-to-maintain code. Find something that's  *fast enough* for your needs and stop there.

Comment: This seems to answer my curiosity. I am not micro-optimizing for fun. In some applications at some bottlenecks, you need to optimize or lose great in performance. This is why I do optimization where I can, to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest way is to stay with `HashSets` and `UnionWith()` They are pretty fast if you want to avoid duplicates.

Example with `HashSet<int>`

```
HashSet<int> set1 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2 };
HashSet<int> set2 = new HashSet<int>() { 2, 3 };
HashSet<int> set3 = new HashSet<int>() { 3, 4 };

set1.UnionWith(set2);
set1.UnionWith(set3);

// set1 {1,2,3,4}
```

In case of `T` is a reference type, you need to override `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`

Comment: `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` only need to be overridden when equality is based on something other than object reference.

Comment: I think you miss my point. You don't **need** to override those methods for reference types. In fact you would only do so in specific circumstances, where equality is based on the object's state rather than the objects own identity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need to combine them?  What about just enumerating all of them in sequence?  Something like this might eliminate the overhead of combining the sets:

```
void Main()
{
    var h1 = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var h2 = new HashSet<int>() { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    var h3 = new HashSet<int>() { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    foreach (var i in enumerateCollections(h1, h2, h3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<T> enumerateCollections<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] collections)
{
    foreach (var coll in collections)
    {
        foreach (var value in coll)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I  would need to pass the function too. This is quite slow. Also foreach inside foreach is performancewise a drawback that is not required. I went with creating a IEnum query and iterate that.