# What is the time complexity of concatenating two Hashsets together in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures

My confusion stems from the fact that most Hashset operations are O(1) time complexity but I was wondering if concatenating two hashsets like the following:

```
HashSet<T> firstSet = new HashSet<T> ();
HashSet<T> secondSet = new HashSet<T> ();

firstSet.Concat(secondSet);
```

is done in linear O(n) time or constant time.

I have checked official documentation and haven't had luck finding performance based specifications.

Comment: O(1) is the complexity for ONE item. If you want to create a new `HashSet` from two others, you must account for N insertions, each one of O(1) complexity.

Comment: `Enumerable.Concat` works on 2 arbitrary `IEnumerable`s, and does not return a set union i.e. if any `T` appears in both sets, it will be duplicated by `Concat`. This clearly must have at least linear complexity.

Comment: See this answer regarding `HashSet` unions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917831/union-vs-unionwith-in-hashset

Comment: The name of the class in .NET is `HashSet<T>` (C# is case sensitive) and there is no `Concat` method but a [HashSet<T>.UnionWith(IEnumerable<T>) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.unionwith). According to the [reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs) (line no 486) the second set is added with `foreach (T item in other) { AddIfNotPresent(item); }`.

Comment: `Enumerable.Concat` is constant time, since it uses 'deferred execution', i.e. it just stores references to both collections in a new object, with an enumerator that returns all items from one collection, and then the other.

Comment: In addition to what @JonasH said, the extension method `Enumerable.Concat` does not eliminate duplicates and is therefore not a set operation! `UnionWith` is a set operation and thus eliminates duplicates. (Note the little [down arrow for extension methods in VS' intellisense](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)!)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes so that means a Concat of two hashsets can actually throw an error if duplicates are found. So its much safer to use UnionWith

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes not quite, it just produces an enumerable collection instead of a hash set.

Comment: @TP95, no ` Enumerable.Concat` produces an `IEnumerable<T>` which may contain duplicates (this is okay if it is what you want). `HashSet<T>.UnionWith` (as well as all the other HashSet operations) never produce duplicates. The attempt to add a duplicate is a no op which never throws an exception. Sets in the [Set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) are non-ordered collections of distinct objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Concat` is an extension method of *Linq* which is *lazy*, i.e. Linq *does nothing* when no action is required. That's why `Concat` itself has evident `O(1)` time complexity - Linq doesn't do anything:

```
// Note, that result is of IEnumerable<T> type
var result = firstSet.Concat(secondSet);
```

However, if we *materialize* `result` we'll have `O(n)` time complexity:

```
// result is HashSet<T>
var result = firstSet
  .Concat(secondSet)  // O(1)
  .ToHashSet();       // O(n)
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can still view and use the contents of `result` without having to materialise it, thus eliminating the extra time to create the hash set.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in some comments, `Concat` would complete in constant time O(1) but would not result in a hash set but rather a list with all items in both hash sets (i.e. you may have duplicates).

`Concat` is constant time because it does not actually create a new collection but an object that can be used to iterate through the items in the concatenated hash sets.

The `UnionWith` method would modify the hash set it was called on to include non duplicate values from a second hash set and executes in linear time / O(N) as stated on the [UnionWith documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.unionwith?view=net-8.0).

Comment: `UnionWith` is `void`, so it does not create a new hashset but modifies the current. You could use Linq's `Union`(instead of `Concat`) to remove duplicates. But then you don't get a hashset.